# Add a member to MS Teams using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-web-app-service, microsoft-teams

I am attempting to add a member to my MS Team using the Graph API and an Azure app token:

```
Endpoint: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/c924e9b8-*****/members

Body:
'@odata.type':'#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember'
'roles':'[]'
'user@odata.bind':'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('41134b16-6f68*****')
```

When I send this request I am getting:

```
"code": "InternalServerError"
"message": "Failed to execute request."
```

I can't seem to find any information on what this error means. Is anyone familiar with this error?

Comment: What programming language or framework do you use for it?

Comment: Hello @Jesse90, the api seems to be working fine when I tried the same from Graph explorer, May i know how you are authenticating using the app token and Can you please provide more details on the same operation ?

Comment: I think you may need to provide a screenshot about how you calling the api or compare with the [api sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-1) if there's anything missing. Then we may check if the parameters you used were incorrect, including token, team id, user id.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'm using PostMan. Here's the code: 

curl --location --request POST 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/c924e9b8-a4b9*****/members' \
--header 'Content-type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6InJkZzFGal...' \
--form '@odata.type="#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember"' \
--form 'roles="[]"' \
--form 'user@odata.bind="https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('\''41134b16-6f68*****'\'')"'
I'm using an Azure Web app token that I created in the developer portal.

Comment: We checked this using postman and it worked fine for us - https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0eYM.png. Could you please check if you have given the required permissions?

Comment: Also please generate a new token and use it for calling the API.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 1):

The issue must be due to Web App token generated from Developer portal.

**Steps to Resolve:**

- Check if the required permissions are provided to the app
  registration you are using for the webapp i.e.
  `TeamMember.ReadWriteNonOwnerRole.All` with admin consent like below :

  [image]
- Go to Postman>>new_request>>authorization>>Select `Oauth2.0 in type`>> select `Grant type as Client Credential`>> fill necessary
  details provided below and then click on new access token.

  ```
  Access Token URL : https://login.microsoftonline.com/my-tenant-id/oauth2/v2.0/token
  ClientId: azure ad App reg ID
  ClientSecret: Secret generated for the same app
  scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
  ```

  [image]
- Once the above is done you will be successfully able to do the
  operation :

  [image]

Comment: I do have TeamMember.ReadWriteNonOwnerRole.All role, in addition to others. Then I call the endpoint https://login.microsoftonline.com/dd8cbebb-2139****/oauth2/v2.0/token? 
which successfully returns a token. I can use this token to call a GET from https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/c924e9b8-a4b9*****/members and that works. But if I try to POST to this endpoint with the body:

'@odata.type': '#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember',
'roles': '[]',
'user@odata.bind': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users(\'41134b16-6f68*****\')'

Comment: Then I get the response: {
    "error": {
        "code": "InternalServerError",
        "message": "Failed to execute request.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-12-07T18:12:27",
            "request-id": "4e7399b5-e15b-43ef-a203-0c81f8e034c4",
            "client-request-id": "4e7399b5-e15b-43ef-a203-0c81f8e034c4"
        }
    }
}

Comment: @Jesse90, can you try removing  \ ? I don't think they are required

Comment: @Jesse90 -Can you please change user@odata.bind in body to below format :   "user@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx72f')"

Comment: Here's a screenshot of what I am trying to do in PostMan ![Valid XHTML](https://imgur.com/jqrgQIX)

Comment: Can you please supply the request body in [a JSON representation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-body) instead of form-data. Attaching a screenshot for your reference. https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWiij.png